# Varible passed to page.evaluate is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When I use `page.evaluate` and pass varibles to it, they are undefined.

```
let reaction;
// First console.log actually logs the string as expected
console.log(reactionTitle);
await this.page.evaluate(function (reactionTitle, reaction) {
    // Second console.log logs undefined in the website's console
    console.log(reactionTitle);
    document.querySelectorAll('span.embedAuthorName-3mnTWj').forEach(s => {
        // Third console.log logs all innerTexts in the website's console
        console.log(s.innerText)
        if (s.innerText == reactionTitle) {
            console.log(s);
            reaction = s.offsetParent.offsetParent.querySelector('.container-1ov-mD').querySelector('.reactions-12N0jA').querySelector('div').querySelector('.reaction-1hd86g').querySelector('.reactionInner-15NvIl');
            console.log(reaction)
        }
    });
}, (reactionTitle, reaction));

console.log(reaction)
```

I put some comments in the code to show where reactionTitle is undefined.

Comment: Please post the error msg which defines what is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from `(reactionTitle, reaction)` in arguments:

```js
await this.page.evaluate((reactionTitle, reaction) => { ... }, reactionTitle, reaction)
```

or

```js
await this.page.evaluate(({reactionTitle, reaction}) => { ... }, {reactionTitle, reaction})
```

---

`page.evaluate` executes in page context and is separate from the puppeteer execution environment. I'd suggest taking look at the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md) and the architecture. To access the variables from in-page context in puppeteer, you need to return the variables. Note that the variables must be serializable:

```js
const result = await this.page.evaluate(({reactionTitle, reaction}) => { 
    ... 
    return reaction;
}, {reactionTitle, reaction});
```

In case the returned value is an in-page object, use [`evaluateHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args).

Comment: Awesome it works now except for the last console.log. `reaction` is still undefined but in the website's console it actually is defined.

Comment: @error2507 that's a different problem. it might be the selectors are changing dynamically. It's hard to tell without seeing the website.

Comment: I can't define `reaction` within `this.page.evaluate`. With your solution I can access `reactionTitle` but I can't define `reaction`. Even if I just try `reaction = 'test'` within the evaluation function it stays undefined. I think it doesn't have to do anything with the site itself.

Comment: @error2507 of course, because reaction is undefined in puppeteer context. these are executing in separate contexts. take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: @error2507 please read my previous comment and the edited answer. 1) if you only need to return the values you don't need to pass reaction as it has no role here. 2) whatever you're returning from `evaluate` **must** be serializable. element nodes are not serializable.